# Simultaneous plotting of a model's training data set and prediction area

Tags: r, ggplot2, prediction, lda, confidence-interval

I wan't to plot training and test dataset of a model in a same plot. I've already tried klaR::partimat, which works fine.

```
set.seed(123)
df.train <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(20,1,1),rnorm(20,2,1),rnorm(20,2,1)),
                       y=c(rnorm(20,2,1),rnorm(20,1,1),rnorm(20,3,1)),
                  z=factor(rep(c(1:3),each=20),levels=c(1:3)))

col_light <- c("lightblue","lightgreen","pink")
klaR::partimat(z ~  x + y , data=df.train, method="lda",prec=250,
               image.colors=col_light, gs=NA, col.mean=NA)

col_dark <- c("blue","darkgreen","red4")
points(df.train,pch=15,col=col_dark[df.train$z])
```

I can do the same "by hand":

```
mdl1 <- MASS::lda(z~x+y,data=df.train)

df.test <- data.frame(x=rep(seq(0,3,length.out=100),each=100),
                      y=rep(seq(0,5,length.out=100),100))
df.test$z <- factor(as.numeric(as.character( predict(mdl1, df.test)[["class"]])),levels=c(1:3))

ggplot(mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,color=z))  +
  geom_point(data=df.test) +
  scale_color_manual(values=col_light)
```

Q1: *How could I add here the training points by the col_dark scheme with ggplot?*

The bootstrap method to calculate 95% percent confidence:

```
for (j in 1:100){
  r1 <- sample(c(1:nrow(df.train)),size=54,replace=FALSE)
  df.train.1 <- df.train[r1,]
  mdl1 <- MASS::lda(z~x+y,data=df.train.1)
  z1 <- factor(as.numeric(as.character( predict(mdl1, df.test)[["class"]])),levels=c(1:3))
  df.test <- cbind(df.test,z1)
  colnames(df.test)[ncol(df.test)] <- paste("z",as.character(j),sep="")
}

mfv <- function(x){ux <- unique(x); ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]}
df.test$z <- apply(df.test[,3:ncol(df.test)], 1, mfv)

df.test$prob <- rowSums(df.test[,3:102]==df.test$z0)
df.test.1 <- df.test[df.test$prob>95,c("x","y","z")]

ggplot(mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,color=z)) +
    geom_point(data=df.test.1) +
    scale_color_manual(values=col_light)
```

Q2: *Is there a better way to plot the prediction areas (e.g. polygons instead of points)?*